# How do you remove a kubernetes context?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was following a tutorial on kubernetes and it told me to run the following commands:

```
kubectl config set-cluster --server=http://127.0.0.1:8080
kubectl config set-context local --cluster=local
kubectl config use-context local
```

Now when I run `kubectl config view` I see an entry for local:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    user: ""
  name: local
```

I was kind of curious about this so I ran the following command:

```
kubectl config set-context testorz --cluster=local
```

Now I see that when I run `kubectl config view`

How do I remove my "testorz" context?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can `kubectl config unset contexts.testorz` to remove that entry.

See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_unset/

Comment: Ah I was trying just unset testorz. Didn't realize it was a "path" that I needed to remove.

Comment: This should be `kubectl config unset contexts.testorz`

Comment: Thanks Matthew Jones! Fixed my answer.

Comment: docs link no longer exists (404)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) you can do it like this

```bash
kubectx -d <NAME>
kubectx -d testorz
```

or to delete current active context

```bash
kubectx -d .
```